# Will JavaScript tag's src attribute follow HTTP redirects in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, http, http-redirect

Let's say, a javascript tag's src attribute points to a redirect:

```
<script src="http://foo.com/foo.js"></script>
```

where http://foo.com/foo.js is a 301 redirect to https://foo.com/foo.js...

Will all browsers successfully load the JS file? I've noticed it seems to work in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE9... but I'm just curious if this is something that's in a spec or just random...

Comment: maybe you should go straight with https

Comment: I think it will. Script requests are just regular browser HTTP requests (which will follow redirects). Unfortunately, I can't really cite anything to support this.

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381100/can-i-use-a-301-redirect-for-included-external-javascript-files and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456095/do-301-redirects-work-for-css-and-js-files-in-a-cross-browser-way?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading resources for a webpage (be it script source, image source or whatever) is agnostic to how browser fetches it for you (using HTTP protocol over TCP/IP).

The only thing to be aware of here is that browser makes two request to download one resource & provided that script calls are blocking in browser, so it is not advised to use this strategy for long. For the 3 very basic reason we use 301s are:

1. Prettify URLs
2. Ensure Link equity
3. Resolve canonical issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the following topic on behavior of different browsers to handle 301 redirect:
[Client Web Browser Behavior When Handling 301 Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666089/client-web-browser-behavior-when-handling-301-redirect)

Comment: +1 I don't think the browser cares whether the url points to a html/php/js etc etc etc page. But for  the life of me i haven't found any documentation to say that ... yet.