# Do 301 redirects work for CSS and JS files in a cross browser way?

Tags: html, browser

Do 301 redirects work for CSS and JS files in a cross browser way?  Like if the page has

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/all.js" ></script>`

and the server returns a 301 redirect to `/js/all2.js`, will the browser seamlessly treat `all2.js` as the correct js file?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, did you try it?

Comment: I tried on Chrome and it works, I'm unable to test on IE though.

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182548/will-javascript-tags-src-attribute-follow-http-redirects-in-all-browsers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381100/can-i-use-a-301-redirect-for-included-external-javascript-files

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

Do I get a few cookies now?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the browser, most desktop browsers will follow the redirect.

Duplicate here:

[Can I use a 301 redirect for included external javascript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381100/can-i-use-a-301-redirect-for-included-external-javascript-)